# Is there an event handler that notifies the user when a tab has been updated?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, tabs

I have multiple tab pages and in each tab page there is datagridview and all datagridview are connected with each other. So let's say I have dgv1 and dgv2, whatever information I update on dgv1 it will calculate automatically and update it on dgv2. So my goal is I want to notify the user dgv2 has been updated, how would I go on to approach that? I'm new to c# thats why I'm not sure how to work with c#form

Comment: You could look into implementing a messaging service; AKA publisher/subscriber service.

Comment: In word, they use a simple star "*" to notify of unsaved changes in any open document/tab. You could use this in the tab name for "Unviewed Changes".